# Javascript filter() function does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a little function which should grab an elements of array "***arr***", then create a new array "***arrNew***" within itself that would contain only the elements of the first array, by the condition that the variable ***func == true***.

Function assignment is to display an elements in array **arr** that consist of condition **arr[i] % 2 == 0.**

For now function work not very good, because - console.log(arr) and the next one results are the same;

```
(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and (7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

.

```
function filter(arr, func) {
  var arrNew = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (func = true) {
        arrNew[i] = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return arrNew;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(arr);
console.log(filter(arr, function(a) {
  return a % 2 == 0;
})); // 2,4,6
```

-------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------

I have change `if (func = true)` on `if (func(arr[i]) == true)` and now function work fine.

But I have an extra problem, when I had added an extra function in file with the first one.
The first is work right, but the second make an error "**func is not a function**" in the first one in the string "**if (func(arr[i]) == true)**". I do not understand why...

So, the displaing of first function is fine. But The second - error :( ...

```
function filter(arr, func) {
  var arrNew = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (func(arr[i]) == true) {
      arrNew.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return arrNew;
}

function inBetween(a, b) {
  var arrayBtw = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= a && arr[i] <= b) {
      arrayBtw.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return arrayBtw;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(filter(arr, function(a) {
  return a % 2 == 0;
})); // 2,4,6

console.log( filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)) ); // 3,4,5,6
```

Comment: You're assigning `true` to the variable holding the function instead of calling the function and comparing the return value.

Comment: It is not the output you expect because you are not filtering, you are just marking Booleans... Second you are not calling func

Comment: Update is a different question entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You have used an assignment operator in place where you should be using a comparison operator. And also you need to use `arr.push()` to append new elements to an array.

Your code needs to be changed as:

```
if (func(arr[i]) === true) {
    arrNew.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Since others have already pointed this out, I'll add something more. To achieve the same results, you can use the built in Javascript `filter` function.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var arrNew = arr.filter(function(a){
            return a % 2 == 0;
        });

console.log(arrNew);
```

Or to do the same in a more concise and a compact way, you can use an `arrow function`.

```
var arrNew = arr.filter(a => a % 2 == 0);
```

This one liner will yield the same result ;) Hope it helps.

=== Answer to the updated question ===

you get the error that `func is not a function` because in the following line, you pass `inBetween(3, 6)` as the second parameter to the `filter` function.

```
console.log(filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)));
```

But your `filter` function is expecting a `function` type as the second parameter and your `inBetween` function is returning an `array` (instead of a "`function`" object). You need to return a `function` from the `inBetween` ;)

If not, and you tried to get numbers which are divisible by two in between 3 and 6, then you have passed the values in the wrong order :) change the order and it will do.

```
console.log(filter(inBetween(3, 6), function (a) {
    return a % 2 == 0;
})); //4,6
```

If you only wanted to get the numbers in between 3 to 6 (without any filtering, referring to your commented expected output), then you don't need the outer filter method call. Just remove it.

```
console.log(inBetween(3, 6)); // 3,4,5,6
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for info about string functions! It's very useful!

Comment: updated the answer to give a hint on your second issue.

Comment: So, I make next:  function inBetween(a, b) {

 return function fun() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i] >= a && arr[i] <= b) {
    return i;
   }
  }
 }

 return;
}

Comment: but it does not help :(

Comment: If you only want to get the numbers in between 3 to 6, you dont need the outer filter() function. just remove that and it will do.

Answer (score 3):

there is some error on the code, first is not

`func = true` is `func(arr[i]) === true`

and instead of `arrNew[i] = arr[i];` you shoud `arrNew.push(arr[i]);`

you need to call the function and you are assigning true to the function not comparing

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (func = true)
```

try

```
if (func(arr[i]) == true)
```

And instead of

```
arrNew[i] = arr[i];
```

try

```
arrNew.push(arr[i]);
```

Also note that JavaScript already has an array filter function, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for details.

Comment: Yep!

Thank you :)

Comment: if you can - help me one more time with this function again... because now "if (func(arr[i]) == true)" is not working... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
if (func = true) {
```

^ This is an assignment. You assign the value `true` to your variable `func`. You want to call the function, so `func(arr[i])` instead of `func`.